# F Sharp The target "Build" does not exist in the project

Tags: f#, visual-studio-code, f#-fake, ionide

Hello I am trying to learn F#, I'd like to compile something in F#

These are the steps that I have followed:

- Downloaded Visual Studio Code
- Downloaded + installed all the Ionide
  extensions
- Ran F# new project, selected console application
- Ran FAKE: build

I then get the error: The target "Build" does not exist in the project.

What are the steps I need to follow to compile a F# solution in Visual Studio Code?

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
  1) Building c:\Users\sfyir\Code\fsharp\ConsoleTest\ConsoleTest.fsproj failed with exitcode 1.
---------------------------------------------------------------------
  2) MSB4057: c:\Users\sfyir\Code\fsharp\ConsoleTest\ConsoleTest.fsproj(0,0): The target "Build" does not exist in the project.
```

Comment: I've seen this before on Linux machines where the `fsharp` package wasn't installed. In your case on Windows, I don't know how to help you specifically, but http://ionide.io/#20150804gettingstarted should have a link and/or some instructions for installing F# correctly on Windows.

Comment: Basically, go to http://fsharp.org/use/windows/ and follow one of the sets of instructions there. Hopefully that's enough to get you started.

Comment: Yes, F# was missing, thank you

Comment: I am getting error with a restore in Mac OS. Using the mono 5.2.0.224 and I did not see any F# specific installation for Mac,  
"error MSB4057: The target "Restore" does not exist in the project.
Running build failed."
While using msbuild getting  error MSB4057: The target "Build" does not exist in the project.